# Disable EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT from being passed to an attached debugger

Tags: windows, debugging, assembly, exception

I'm dealing with an anti-debug application which disables EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT from being passed to my debugger, instead it executes its SEH and UnhandledExceptionFilters.

- I tried it with 3 different debuggers (even selfmade one)
- My debugger receives other debug events like LOAD_DLL, CREATE_THREAD etc
- Exceptions are not passed when first chance debugging aswell as last chance
- Breakpoint events of my own created threads get passed to the debugger, so the anti-debug method must be thread specific and may be a modification of the ThreadInformationBlock
- There's no kernel mode access

So how can it be possible in usermode to pass EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT (for only one thread, not affecting the whole process) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well.. the solution is rather simple:

call

```
NtSetInformationThread(
  IN HANDLE               ThreadHandle,
  IN THREAD_INFORMATION_CLASS ThreadInformationClass,
  IN PVOID                ThreadInformation,
  IN ULONG                ThreadInformationLength );
```

with `ThreadHideFromDebugger ( 0x11 )` as `ThreadInformationClass`.